# Example of module homomorphism?

Tags: modules

I would like to come up with an example for a module homomorphism between two finitely generated, not free modules over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Also, what would be the kernel and image in this example?

Comment: What do you know about homomorphisms?  In other words, what property would such a function have to satisfy?

Comment: I know that addition and multiplication by a scalar would be preserved for a homomorphism, but I'm having trouble coming up with a specific example that fits all those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

How about the identity map $M\to M$, where $M$ is any non-free, finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module?

Do you know how to construct such a thing?  Hint: It may be easier to first consider $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Are there any examples with two distinct modules that would work?

Comment: @user223365 Yes.  But it would be good to start with one... always work on the easiest problem that you don't know how to do.

Comment: I see, are there any suggestions you can offer for how to produce such a module M?

Comment: Would a cyclic module M = Ra work? Would it be non-free?

Comment: @user223365 It might be best to work with a ring you are familiar with, such as $\mathbb{Z}$.  What are the cyclic $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?  If you can find two, $M$ and $N$, then the zero map $M\to N$ is a homomorphism between two non-free modules.